# MySQL. Subtract data from table2 in table1

Tags: mysql

Simple question, but I don't get the way to acomplish it.

```
Table 1.
ID    Quantity
1     4
2     5
3     2

Table 2
ID    Quantity
2     1
3     2
```

I want the query to obtain the following result:

```
Table result
ID    Quantity
1     4
2     4
```

I have been looking for something related with MINUS operator or NOT IN, but the thing is I want to substract the quantity in the same query.

EDIT: Table 1 is always bigger than Table 2. Table 2 can't contain id's that are not present in table 1.

I hope the example clarifies the question.

Regards!!

Comment: How did you end up with a (2, 4) row?

Comment: Table 1. Row ID 2 -> Quantity = 5 Table 2. ID 2 -> Quantity 1 So, in table result, ID 2 is 5-1 = 4

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve; don't let us reverse-engineer your thought from the desired result. If I understand correctly, you'd like to subtract Quantity of Table 2 from Quantity of Table 1 for each ID, not returning anything if result is 0. Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45621446/edit) and explain?

Comment: Just subtract the quantities from table 2 in table 1 and return the table result. Like I wrote in the example

Comment: You're still being vague. Is table 1 always larger than table 2? Can table 2 contain IDs not in table 1. You need to be specific when asking for help.

Comment: Yes, table 1 is always larger than table 2 and table 2 can't contain IDs not in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic use-case of a join:

```
SELECT table1.value - COALESCE(table2.value, 0) AS value
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.value != table2.value
-- insert order by clauses/etc if needed
```

This will compute the values of table2's value minus table1's. [You can get a good overview of different joins here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). This uses a left join, which will only include results where there are ids in both `table1` and `table2` that match, and then uses `COALESCE` to turn the `null`/non-match from table2 into a `0`.

The last statement's purpose is to finally remove results which equate to 0, so this would not include the `(3, 0)` result.

You can also use this join to [create a view of the output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html), which has advantages like caching and speeding up your lookups.

Comment: Thank you Rogue, Can you explain a litle bit more the last line? #insert where clauses/etc if needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's a comment signifying any additional logic you felt the need to include in your statement (e.g. if you wanted only the results where the `id` is `2`). I used the wrong comment character, fixed.

Comment: This will not add the (1, 4) row to the result, since table 2 does not have an ID = 1 row and you are using an INNER JOIN.

Comment: I missed a bit of the question, fixing.

Comment: Your WHERE should be `table1.value > table2.value`, since a larger value in table2 would give a negative value which I assume should be removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Quantity - COALESCE(T2.Quantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you Girish007 I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.value - IFNULL(table2.value, 0) AS value
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table1.value > table2.value
```

To walk you through the above query. You use a `LEFT JOIN` here to combine your two tables. `LEFT JOIN` is specifically used since not all table 1 IDs all guaranteed to appear in table 2, but you still want to output these results. You use the ID in your `ON` condition since that is how you are matching the tables. You need to include the `IFNULL` statement since table 1 IDs with no matching table 2 IDs will result in NULL table 2 values for that joined row. You then subtract these two values to obtain your result. The `WHERE` clause here will remove rows which would have returned a value equal to or less than zero.